# Use image as icon with react-select

Tags: reactjs, image, require, react-select

I would like to add an image as Icon with react-select. I did all right but I have a problem with the fact that, in react, images are written like this :

```
<img src={require(...)} />
```

So I use react-select like this :

```
const IconOption = (props) => (

  <Option {... props}>
    <div>
      <img src={require(props.data.image)} />
    </div>
  </Option>
);
```

And then call for the select box :

```
render() {
    return (
      <Select
        classNamePrefix="react-select"
        placeholder={"Search..."}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        components={{ DropdownIndicator: () => null, Option: IconOption }}
        options={this.state.options}
        openMenuOnClick={false}
        styles={customStyle}
      />
    );
  }
```

I tried to write :

```
const IconOption = (props) => (

  <Option {... props}>
    <div>
      {props.data.image}
    </div>
  </Option>
);
```

Which gives me :

```
./css/img/PROFILEPICTURE.jpg
```

It is exactly what I want to get, the path is correct. If I exactly write :

```
const IconOption = (props) => (

  <Option {... props}>
    <div>
      <img src="./css/img/PROFILEPICTURE.jpg" />
    </div>
  </Option>
);
```

Image is correctly displayed.

If I write the first code, which is the one to get different picture for each item in selectbox, I got an error :

[image]

Any solution to not use require function for img in react?

Edit :

I also tried :

```
const IconOption = (props) => 
  (
    <Option {... props}>
      <div>
        <img src={props.data.image} />
        {props.data.label}
      </div>
    </Option>
  );
```

And i got not found images :

[image]

Comment: could you please provide link to sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to remove the `require` since your image is not part of the compiled react app:

```
const IconOption = (props) => (
  <Option {... props}>
    <div>
      <img src={props.data.image} />
    </div>
  </Option>
);
```

Comment: I edited my initial question to answer to your solution. I indeed forgot to say that I already tried it.

Comment: I just learned that it is possible to not use require ONLY if you use public folder and then get it with <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/PROFILPICTURE.jpg'}. I will just do like this. Is it dangerous?

Comment: @Kuartz In my opinion this should be absolutely ok